# vba excel match on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

any help would be appreciated. this looks like a common question, but I couldn't find any in vba. Here's my best shot:

```
Dim oppositeRow As Long
.....
oppositeRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(ddate & campaign, "A3:B62", 0)
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: i wanted to know a way to get the match position from 2 criteria. My above code did not work. the two conditions there are the strings `ddate` and `campaign`

Comment: `Match` can only evaluate on 1 criterion, and 1 column at a time.  It sounds like a need a query.

Comment: Use a SumIfs formula. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx

Comment: @HeadofCatering, that sounds like a great avenue to pursue, but how could I get row number from that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that there will only be one matching result, you can do the following as an Excel formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A2:A5), N("john"=A2:A5), N("smith"=B2:B5))
```

as applied to the following worksheet:

```
      A      B
1     first  last
2     bob    smith
3     john   smith    
4     john   brown
5     sam    brown
```

This will return 3 (since john smith is on the third row), you will have to subtract 1 to get the index into the table because of the header row.

This works by multiplying together three vectors:

1. The first, ROW(A2:A5), is just {2,3,4,5}.
2. The second, N("john"=A2:A5), is {0,1,1,0}.  The N() takes the vector {false,true,true,false} and converts it to numbers.
3. The third, N("smith"=B2:B5), is {1,1,0,0}.  Same deal with the N().

Multiplying the vectors together element-wise gets {0,3,0,0}, the sum of which is 3.

It is somewhat awkward to express a complicated formula like that in VBA, so if you want to do it purely in VBA I'd recommend just doing a loop with a counter and recording the index where you found a row matching your criteria.

Edit: here is some VBA code:

```
Dim index as Integer
For index = 1 to 4
    If Range("A1").Offset(index).Value = "john" And Range("B1").Offset(index).Value = "smith" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next index
```

Comment: I would like to do it purely in vba. doing the loop and counter might be complicated though because each value appears more than once in their own columns, but only once together in the same row.

Comment: @mango The loop is actually simple because you can check multiple conditions on each loop.  For example:  
  
    `Dim index as Integer  
    For index = 1 to 4  
        If Range("A1").Offset(index).Value = "john" And Range("B1").Offset(index).Value = "smith" Then  
            Exit For  
        End If  
    Next index`

Comment: I have to admit, I didn't think that would be so simple. Let me give it a test. Hope there aren't severe performance losses for this.

Comment: absolutely fantastic! you've saved my life! worked great but one should note that in the loop `index + 1` was the actual value that I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with the `DGET` formula, as long as you add a column to your worksheet that is used to represent the row number.

```
rowID  column1  column2
1       A       aa
2       B       bb
3       C       cc
4       D       dd
5       E       ee
```

The formula is then:

```
=DGET(A1:C6;1;E1:F2)
```

This assumes that the above data is in `A1:C6`  The below block of data, which includes the search criteria is placed in `E1:F2`

```
column1  column2
C        cc
```

The return value of the `DGET` formula listed above is '3'.

You can do this purely in VBA if your VBA method places the proper search criteria into cells `E2` and `F2` prior to running the `DGET` formula.

Comment: i can see how this would work. but this would prove far too inelegant for my uses. If i could have went as far with this, I utilize equally inelegant methods.

Comment: Your best bet then is to use Alex Godofsky's solution, so you don't need to worry about any Excel Worksheet functions.  It can all be done in code.

Comment: thanks for your attention and help!